# Twitter Bootstrap autocompleter with JSON

Tags: spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have been attempting to get a Twitter Bootstrap autocompleter working with a Spring MVC annotated controller.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="name">Supplier</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="supplier" name="supplier" class="input-xlarge" data-provide="typeahead" type="text"/>    
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the following javascript:

```
<script src="/resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/resources/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#supplier').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.get('http://localhost:8080/supplier/search', { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        },

        minLength : 3,
        items : 4,
        property: 'name'
    });
    </script>
```

when a type three letters I am seeing the correct request to my controller which is returning a single supplier object as JSON:

```
{"supplier":{"name":"test","id":0,"version":0,"url":null}}
```

However, the text field is not showing the returned supplier. Can anyone provide any help as to why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`process()`](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js#L93) expects an array of *strings* instead of an array of *objects*. Thus, instead of passing it an object, pass it an array with the contents that you want to be shown on the text field, i.e., `[ "test" ]`.

Also, as a suggestion, to use `typeahead` with remote sources, I'd suggest using this [plugin](https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead) instead. Amongst other things, it allows you to use an array of objects instead of an array of strings.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll take a look at that plugin now.

Comment: @Alex: It's really great, I've used it a couple of times in my projects. Here are some demos: https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/demo/js/demo.js

Comment: I've been playing with this plugin and I'm making progress. In the Ajax example the source data looks different in format to the JSON in my question. Is my source data wrongly formatted?

Comment: @Alex: You seem to be returning an object, whereas most autocomplete/typeahead plugins expect an array. Can you return an *array* of suppliers instead, i.e., `[ {"name":"test1","id":1,"version":0,"url":null}, {"name":"test2","id":2,"version":0,"url":null} ]`?

Comment: I'll give it a go. I was just letting Spring do its magic and not interfering! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#supplier').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.get('http://localhost:8080/supplier/search', { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        },
Replace the above code to the below one

$('#supplier').typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/supplier/search')?>",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                max_rows: 15,
                search_key: query,
                ajax: 1
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var return_list = [], i = data.length;
                while (i--) {
                    return_list[i] = {Name: data[i].Name, value: data[i].Name'};
                }
                typeahead.process(return_list);
            }
        });
    },
    onselect: function(obj) {
        $('[name="name"]').val(obj.id);
    }
});
```